# Drawing shapes with lines in JAVA

Tags: java, lines, shapes, trigonometry

So I am having a big problem with drawing shapes using only lines. Lets say I start to draw a line from a point on the middle of the screen and draw it forward at 100 distance in pixels and with angle 0 then I draw another line of the same length using angle 72 degrees and so on until 360 degrees. It should give me perfect pentagon where one line ends and another starts from that point, but the lines do not meet on the end it works perfect for squares where angles are 0/90/180/270 but I need to make it work for each shape even circles. I am using this thing for calculations:

```
_endingPointX = (_currentPostisionX + distance * _cosinuses[_angle]);

_endingPointY = (_currentPostisionY + distance * _sinuses[_angle]);
```

Where _cosinuses and _sinuses are arrays of doubles that contain the values for sinuses and cosinuses for each one of 360 degrees. And when drawing a line I need to cast these values to integer.

drawLine(_currentPostisionX, _currentPostisionY, (int) _endingPointX, (int) _endingPointY);

I do not know how to fix this and make the lines meet at the end of drawn shape. Been trying to figure out this for a few days but nothing comes to my mind.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Problem is solved thank you for the advice guys it was my mistake with using integer casting.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the lines do not meet on the end"? Where do they end instead? Could you post a screenshot? That would really help to find the problem.

Comment: Here you go with the print screen of it I marked it inside the red circle. http://imgur.com/VglD1

Comment: Keep type of all coordinate variables as doubles, and do all calculations as doubles. Also, try using the math functions instead of pre-calc tables. Does that fix the inaccuracy?

Comment: @hyde Well I can store them in double variables, because built in Java function that draws a line needs integer cords and all I can do is to cast these cords for ints.

Comment: @Philipp Maybe this shows how it works F(arg) draws a line using set angle A(arg) increase the angle of a one given in an argument and it draws that using iterations number I can change all of these args to draw whatever I want but since it does not draw shapes correctly here is what it gives me drawing the same line 100 times changing angle of 72 with each iteration. http://i.imgur.com/XZhUP.png When all it was supposed to do is to draw and redraw the same pentagon in a place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate all values in double and round immediately before drawing.
Do not calculate further with the rounded ones.

To draw a pentagon or a n- gon use something similar to:

```
     // number of corners of pentagon
    double numVertex = 5;
    // how much to change the angle for the next corner( of the turtle )
    double angleStep = 360.0 / numVertex;
    gc.moveTo(cx, cy - rad);
    for (int i= 1; i < numVertex; i++) {
         // total angle from 0 degrees
         double angle = i* angleStep;
         // px point of turtle is corner of pentagon
         double px = cx + rad * sin(angle * DEG_TO_RADIANS);
         // move turtle to
         gc.lineto((int)Math.round(px),
         (int)Math.round(py));
    }
     gc.lineTo(cx, cy - rad);
```

If you use `lineTo` instead line chances are higher that the points meet.

Comment: I should have added this at the begining of my question it is a Turtle program for modeling with L-systems in 2D that is why I can never predict what is going to be drawn and I need that precision.

Comment: ok, but it will work using double as current coordinate of the turtle, do not use int for that. only use int for drawing

Comment: @Paul Note that inaccuracy will still creep in. You should probably test how fast, for example by making a million of these pentagons, starting the first from (0,0) and seeing how far the starting point drifts.

Answer (score 0):

It does not perfectly line up due to rounding errors resulting from precision of sin and cos functions. To fix this, you can store the starting point as a separate variable, and use it as an ending point for the last line.

Comment: It is pointless because I can never predict what kind of shape I am going to draw.

Comment: If you know the amount of sections in the shape, you can just use an if switch when it is at the last section (amount-1) and construct a line from the currentposititon to the starting position.

Comment: see my code too, it is better to moce to the start oosition, ratgee than calculating it again, (but that would work too)

Answer (score 0):

If you just rely on `int` values, you will have accuracy issues because `sin(72°)` is irrational, while `sin(90°)` is not of course.

But you can draw [`Line2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html) in both `double` or `float` precision, or use [`GeneralPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) [which uses `float`].